# Securing Apache with Django authentication

Tags: django, apache

I have an ImageField in one of my Django models.  Each of these images has a user (or group of users) who have access to them; no other users should be able to see them.

The ImageField stores the image file in the media root. Any web request for that image via the image path) bypass django and get served directly by Apache.

How do I ensure that only the users that are authorized to request the images can actually get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add new view for serve image and store image in other path, apache cant server new path

now in new view check group of user serve image
and if not your user send 403

```
@login_required
def serve_file(request, context):
    if <check if they have access to the file>:
        filename = "/var/www/myfile.xyz" 
        response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download') 
        response['Content-Disposition']='attachment;filename="%s"'%filename
        response["X-Sendfile"] = filename
        response['Content-length'] = os.stat("debug.py").st_size
        return response
    return <error state>
```